# lm doesn't work with wildcard filter

Tags: windbg

I'm trying to filter loaded modules with `lm` command.

But `lm *SHELL*` still lists all modules (expecting `SHELL32` only)

So, does lm command support that? Or what alternatives can I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the 'm' option to specify a wildcard. lm m *SHELL* ought to work.

See

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552026(v=vs.85).aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/debuggingtoolbox/archive/2008/04/16/special-command-use-lm-and-get-all-details-from-modules.aspx